# How to use elasticsearch for smart(simple) searching on marketplace?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm still learning elastic and a lot of things are unclear to me, including this example:
Suppose I have marketplace like amazon/any (many products with many sub options and availability by cities). And I want use elastic for searching only by string field.
For example I want to search "lord of the rings compilation in dublin" and elastic should return only books compilation on lord of the rings which availability in dublin.

Into elastic I can put documents with any schema (using only for searching).

So now I have this schema for elastic (data compilation from prod database):

```
[
  {
    "name": "lord of rings",
    "seller": "Home Production",
    "availability": [
      {
        "city": "dublin",
        "category": "book",
        "types": [
          "one book",
          "compilation"
        ]
      },
      {
        "city": "london",
        "category": "book",
        "types": [
          "one book",
          "compilation"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "lord of rings",
    "seller": "Some",
    "availability": [
      {
        "city": "dublin",
        "category": "book",
        "types": [
          "one book",
          "compilation"
        ]
      },
      {
        "city": "london",
        "category": "book",
        "types": [
          "one book",
          "compilation"
        ]
      },
      {
        "city": "dublin",
        "category": "dvd",
        "types": [
          "disk"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is a very abstract example. We can format the data schema in any way for ease of searching. The search city is always known (it is not part of the text query).
The difficulty is that one seller, for one product, has many cities of availability and in each city we know the "options" of availability (for example, one book or a whole collection)
I don't know how to describe it in more detail or how to find it in Google correctly.
I tried multi_match but it gives wrong answers if i want 'lord of rings dvd in dublin'.
He suggests that the first document is more relevant to me, although in fact the second document is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Relevance issues are not easy to solve, sometimes you could get better results if you boost the city field using multi-match.
Anyway, you need to study more to understand your scenario and make the documents you want more relevant.

I recommend that you read the book [Relevant Search](https://www.manning.com/books/relevant-search) that will help you a lot to understand why some results are not relevant as you want.